# Effect of H-bonding on o-nitrobenzoic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, aromatic-compounds, carbonyl-compounds, nitro-compounds

[image: 2-nitrobenzoic acid]

My argument here is regarding the **acidity of o-nitrobenzoic acid** being greater than p,m-nitrobenzoic acid. In o-nitrobenzoic acid, there is an **intramolecular hydrogen bond** which makes the bond stronger and resists the release of H+ ion. Also going by that along with *ortho effect* in check shouldn't acidity of o-nitrobenzoic acid be relatively lesser? To what extent does hydrogen bonding affect the acidity?

Comment: The  intramolecular Hydrogen bonding here is not possible to occur. If you don't see it obviously, I will suggest you to make a $3D$ model to visualise. The hydrogen is far away from the oxygen on the nitro group, as both the group doesn't remain in the same plane. Also, by ortho effect, the acidity doesn't at all become lesser, it is increased for sure.

Comment: @Soumik Das. But H can form Hydrogen bond with nitrogen right

Comment: @dhaneshvijay Not really.. Because for forming Hydrogen bonds, the other atom should be highly electronegative and most importantly rich in electron density. Here the Nitrogen in Nitro group is positively charged, which makes it electron deficienct and not suitable for hydrogen bonding in this case.

Comment: Steric inhibition due to resonance is more important here rather than the H-bonding. Also won't ortho effect make ortho most acidic?